# Freeze/snapshot CSS & get values

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design, css-transitions

I've added [transitions](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/) to smooth out the CSS changes in responsive to viewport width. At one point it seems like one of the outer (~top level) `div`s go down to a width of zero and back up to the desired width again.

#### Is there anyway to *'pause'* the CSS and see which `div` is causing the strange visual effect?

---

There's a few media queries and a lot of CSS (which I didn't write) so I'd just like to be able to take a snapshot of the style at the point where the width looks like it is zero.

I'm running this locally so this isn't available online to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This blog post shows some interesting techniques - perhaps they could be of help: http://britg.com/2012/01/15/forging-forgecraft-integrating-css3-transitions-with-javascript/.

Comment: Can you add it into jsfiddle to review?

Comment: @justinavery No, it's way too long. I was hoping there would be a nice way of troubleshooting problems like this in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try to console.log($(yourTopLevelDiv).width()) all along the transition, this way you'll be able to see if the problem come from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/qf3L3/

Comment: Right now, this is the only option